# Powershell Multidimensional associative table

Tags: powershell, multidimensional-array, wmi

Greatings, I'm trying to extract WMI informations with Powershell in order to push them in a Mysql DB via PHP.
If a machine has no access to the internet, I export an XML file (that is working).

```
$filePath = $PSScriptRoot + '\processors.xml'
$XmlWriter = New-Object System.XMl.XmlTextWriter($filePath,$Null)

$processor = Get-WmiObject Win32_Processor

$xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("Processor")
foreach ($item in $processor){
$xmlWriter.WriteStartElement($item.DeviceID)
$xmlWriter.WriteElementString("Name",$item.Name)
$xmlWriter.WriteElementString("AddressWidth",$item.AddressWidth)
$xmlWriter.WriteElementString("NumberOfCores",$item.NumberOfCores)
$xmlWriter.WriteElementString("NumberOfLogicalProcessors",$item.NumberOfLogicalProcessors)
$xmlWriter.WriteElementString("L2CacheSize",$item.L2CacheSize)
$xmlWriter.WriteElementString("L3CacheSize",$item.L3CacheSize)
$xmlWriter.WriteEndElement()
}
$xmlWriter.WriteEndElement()

$xmlWriter.Finalize
$xmlWriter.Flush()
$xmlWriter.Close()
```

But if a machine has access to the internet, I prefer to push informations directly to a page, via HTTP POST, which will verify informations and store them in the DB.
Here is my problem, as I don't know the number of items (here processors but imagine with memories, hard drives... etc.) I use a foreach statement to create the XML file (and it works) but, I don't know how to create the equivalent structure to create and fill a multi dimensionnal arry $postprocessor that stores CPUs informations. I have tried the following code but I'm stuck (that is not working) :

```
$processor = Get-WmiObject Win32_Processor

$postprocessor = @()
foreach ($item in $processor){
    $itemarr = @()
    $itemarr += 'Name="'+$item.Name+'"'
    $itemarr += 'AddressWidth="'+$item.AddressWidth+'"'
    $itemarr += 'NumberOfCores="'+$item.NumberOfCores+'"'
    $itemarr += 'NumberOfLogicalProcessors="'+$item.NumberOfLogicalProcessors+'"'
    $itemarr += 'L2CacheSize="'+$item.L2CacheSize+'"'
    $itemarr += 'L3CacheSize="'+$item.L3CacheSize+'"'
    $postprocessor.Add($item.DeviceID+'='+$itemarr)
    # write-host $itemarr
    Remove-Variable itemarr
}

$postParams = $postprocessor
$sending = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri http://localhost:8080/wmi/test.php -Method POST -Body $postParams
```

In fact I just wanted to store those informations like this :

```
$postParam[]
 $postProcessors[]
  ->Processor1[]
   ->Name = value
   ...
   ->L3Cachesize = value
  ->Processor2[]
   ->Name = value
   ...
   ->L3Cachesize = value
 postMemories[...]
 postHardDrives[...]
 etc
```

Maybe I have not found previous answer that solve my problem, if it is the case excuse me by advance and I'll be glad to read as many links that you'll send to me.
Best

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you'd probably need is a dictionary and not an array of arrays.

```
$processor = Get-WmiObject Win32_Processor

$postprocessor = @{}
foreach ($item in $processor){
    $itemHash = @{
        Name = $item.Name
        AddressWidth = $item.AddressWidth
        NumberOfCores = $item.NumberOfCores
        NumberOfLogicalProcessors = $item.NumberOfLogicalProcessors
        L2CacheSize = $item.L2CacheSize
        L3CacheSize = $item.L3CacheSize
    }

    $postprocessor.Add($item.DeviceID, $itemHash)
}

$postParams = $postprocessor
```

This is what I see in the output.

```
PS C:\> $postprocessor

Name                           Value                                                                                                                                                                                                          
----                           -----                                                                                                                                                                                                          
CPU0                           {Name, NumberOfCores, AddressWidth, NumberOfLogicalProcessors...}                                                                                                                                              



PS C:\> $postprocessor["cpu0"]

Name                           Value                                                                                                                                                                                                          
----                           -----                                                                                                                                                                                                          
Name                           Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3630QM CPU @ 2.40GHz                                                                                                                                                                      
NumberOfCores                  4                                                                                                                                                                                                              
AddressWidth                   64                                                                                                                                                                                                             
NumberOfLogicalProcessors      8                                                                                                                                                                                                              
L2CacheSize                    1024                                                                                                                                                                                                           
L3CacheSize                    6144

PS C:\> ConvertTo-Json -InputObject $postprocessor
{
    "CPU0":  {
                 "Name":  "Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3630QM CPU @ 2.40GHz",
                 "NumberOfCores":  4,
                 "AddressWidth":  64,
                 "NumberOfLogicalProcessors":  8,
                 "L2CacheSize":  1024,
                 "L3CacheSize":  6144
             }
}
```

Comment: Ahah, it works but I'll have to figure how to push it to my $_POST php var.
When I do a :
`code` if($_POST) {file_put_contents("my_array.json", json_encode($_POST));}"
I got the result in my file my_array.json :
`code`{"reference":"System.Collections.Hashtable","processor":"System.Collections.Hashtable","computer":"System.Collections.Hashtable","physicalmemory":"System.Collections.Hashtable","machine":"System.Collections.Hashtable"}

I'll surely find a way !

Comment: if what you want is json, use ConvertTo-Json. Updated my answer.

Comment: In fact I used json only in the php backend in order to debug the $_POST var. My final need is to send via HTTP POST the wmi request from computers in order to populate a Mysql database.
By the way, many thanks for your answers and your time ! I didn't know that Powershell can create json objects !

Comment: I have the feeling that I can't push those elements that way directly to the web page. But it seems to be the fastest way : launch the script, the computer details are in the DB !
Another possible way is, maybe you will advice me, to generate the XML file and from the same script to send it via HTTP POST...